# Is there any time limit for database in firebase free spark plan?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I wanted to use firebase free Spark plan for a small project. Does Firebase have any time limit for the data stored in the free plan, like does it delete that data after some duration?

Comment: In addition to Dharmaraj's answer, I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69267458/firebaseerror-quota-exceeded-how-to-shut-down-snapshot-listener-firebase) might also help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any restriction on how long the data is stored. As long as the project is active and you don't delete data yourself, it'll be there.

The restrictions on the Spark plan are only how much data you can store and download.