# Message "The files could not be uploaded because the quota for this project has been exceeded" on Firebase Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

A few hours ago I uploaded a video on Firebase Storage of 80 mb, now I got this message "The files could not be uploaded because the quota for this project has been exceeded" and I can no longer use the data stored in the Storage and Realtime database.
[image: Firebase screenshot]

I can't even delete the video that takes up space because I get the error message. How can I delete the video?

Comment: I think that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69267458/firebaseerror-quota-exceeded-how-to-shut-down-snapshot-listener-firebase) will also help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds your project is on the free Spark plan of Firebase, in which case there is a limit on the amount of data you can read and write per day - as shown in the [Firebase pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) page.

You will either have to upgrade the project to the paid Blaze plan to remove that limit, or wait a day for the free, daily quota to reset.